# Using variable value in for loop parameter

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to write a simple program:
to ask user two numbers and print the *even* numbers between them;

```
x, y = input("Enter a two value: ").split()

for num in range (x,y):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print (num)
```

x,y  can not use in a for loop parameter.

Question is: what is the easy way - without using multiple line functions - to use two input numbers (space or comma separated) in a for loop?

I tried split(), int() and eval()

Comment: It seems you forgot to pass the parameter to the split function

Comment: @AntonDikarev `split` arguments are optional, by default it splits by whitespace.

Comment: Even after fixing x and y your code will print even numbers, not odd numbers - you need to change 0 to 1 in the if statement.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `x` and `y` objects are of type `str` so `range(x, y)` does not work as expected.

There are multiple options to use from to convert the input to integers.

Using list comprehension:

```
x, y = [int(elt) for elt in input("Enter a two value: ").split()]
```

Using `map()`:

```
x, y = map(int, input("Enter a two value: ").split())
```

Or convert explicitly in the loop parameter itself:

```
range (int(x), int(y))
```

Note: This assumes that the input is separated by the space delimiter. You can have a look at `re.split()` if you want to split by multiple delimiters.

Further, as @norie pointed correctly in the comments, the logic to get the odd numbers is incorrect and it should be:

```
if num % 2 == 1:  # instead of 0
```